# How to find integrated power of a optical signal using wavelength amplitude graph?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, fiber-optics

I have a wavelength amplitude graph as shown below.
[image]
This a screenshot captured from optical spectrum analyzer.  From the image I can see what is the power at each wavelength. But, I would like to connect this to a photo-detector and see its integrated power. As you could have noticed the power of the light in each wavelength is only in terms of picowatt so it is not measurable by a normal optical power meter.  So how can I find the integrated power in all wavelength like what an optical power meter do?